# How to set "PHP output_buffering On" through htaccess or PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site is on a shared server, no access to `php.ini` and `output buffering` is set as `no value`.

I have also tried this `.htacces` but no help (tried without third line as well):

```
1.   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
2.   php_flag output_buffering On
3.   php_value output_buffering 8192
4.   php_value output_handler mb_output_handler
5. </IfModule>
```

I actually need it as I want to call `ob_start()` before a header location in middle of a PHP Page as it is sending me - `Header already started error`.

Thanks in advance.

---

Also, if someone can help me with a javascript based script which autodownload an exe file on page load (Without any extra page pop up).

---

Script I am using is:

```
           // <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           .
           .
           .
           // Sending Mails and other stuff

           if ($mail->send()) {
                $alertSuccess = 1;
                $alertMsg = "Your license has been sent succesfully.";

                ## Download Installer
                $folder = "license";
                $file = "Setupn.msi";
                ob_start();
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile("$folder/$file");
            }
```

Comment: I suspect the error has nothing to do with the ob settings etc, but just with your script sending output to the browser before you want to.  Can you post a minimal example of your php script?

Comment: STOP! Don't proceed any further! Change the encoding of your file from `UTF-8` to `UTF-8 without BOM`. (For the js, use `<script>location="exe file";</script>` or similar. Without js is better).

Comment: And for your JS question; this is a totally different topic, you should ask it in another question.

Comment: I have just edited my question above. Could you please check Ismael/Giorgio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want that

```
       if ($mail->send()) {
            $alertSuccess = 1;
            $alertMsg = "Your license has been sent succesfully.";

            ## Download Installer
            $folder = "license";
            $file = "Setupn.msi";
            ob_clean(); // clear your current output and set headers for your download
            // its not possible to remove already setted headers with ob_clean
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            flush();
            readfile("$folder/$file");
            exit; // i prefere an exit here, to stop all other scripts
        }
```

i prefere to output a normal page with your message and then redirect your user via js to your download.

Comment: Hi A. Blub. I tried this, but it is again giving me the same "Headers not sent issue and whole download is getting printed in browser instead of download.". Also, I cannot exit it at last as I have to show HTML after this download.

Comment: Oh sorry, its not possible to remove the headers with ob_clean